# Pip install pygwalker failed due to setuptools version not found

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

pygwalker failure despite setuptools already installed

```
pip install pygwalker --use-pep517  --proxy=\<proxy\>:\<port\>
```

Output:

```
Collecting pygwalker
  Using cached pygwalker-0.3.15-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (19 kB)
Collecting appdirs (from pygwalker)
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: arrow in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from pygwalker) (1.3.0)
Collecting astor (from pygwalker)
  Using cached astor-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting duckdb<=0.8.1 (from pygwalker)
  Using cached duckdb-0.8.1.tar.gz (10.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020F413C32F0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020F413F5B20>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020F4157E840>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020F4157E7B0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020F4157E9F0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

```
pip show setuptools
```

shows

```
Name: setuptools
Version: 68.2.2
Summary: Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python packages
Home-page: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools
Author: Python Packaging Authority
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org
License:
Location: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

Specifying --use-pep517 is a must otherwise there will be another error prompting installation with pep517.

Comment: Your issue is the `ConnectTimeoutError`. Try `pip --timeout=1000 install setuptools>=40.8.0`

Comment: Hi I've tried that but it is still giving the same error